# WCF with MVC application and mobile app

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, xamarin, ninject

I'm just wondering how to approach to my project.
In my application I have:

1. MVC4 project
2. DB_Project with Interfaces and Models
3. Repository_Project with interfaces implemantation - I'm using Ninject

Next step is mobile app(XAMARIN), and here is the question:

1. What kind of WCF project should I choose and why...WCF Service Application or  WCF Service Library?
2. Should I add this project like any other or create separate one?
3. After choosing WCF project, how to use reference to Repository_Project - is this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some thoughts to consider.

1- Your Xamarin app must communicate with an asp.net web api / mvc exposed to the internet. I dont recommend exposing a WCF service to the internet for many reasons.

2- In the Data layer, repositories are abstractions to access your EF dbContext and not to call WCF services.

3- You only add complexity when justified. If you are willing to create WCF project for the xamarin app to communicate with, then i hardly discourage you. WCF project may be created in your case if you have some security policy that enforces 3-tiers architecture where the web api needs a middle tier to access the database. Otherwise, you dont need it.

2-tiers:

Xamarin -> web api -> SQL Server

3-tiers:

Xamarin -> web api -> wcf -> SQL Server

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I have 3-tiers in my app.
Right now I have created another project inside my App - WCF Service Application. 
In this project I have added ADO.NET Entity Data Model. 
Is this the right direction?

Comment: could you take a look at my answer - sorry I can't edit the previous one

Comment: You create a .Data class library project where your EF DbContext resides. As such, you create a .Entities class library project where your EF entities reside. You can generate your EF entities and DbContext with new ado.net entity data model -> and choose code first from database. Then, your service application must reference .Entities and .Data layers and use them.

Comment: I'm little confused. Right now my app looks like this: 1. MVC_Project 2. Service_Project 3. Repository_Project 4. DB_Project 5. WCFServiceApplication Just as you suggest I have moved EntityDataModel to the DB_Project. Now: MVC_Controller -> Service -> Repositories -> DB(I'm able to get or set values in DB tables with NINJECT). Next: How to make use of service_layer in WCFSeriviceApplication? I tried with Ninject.Extension.WCF, but it gives me error in creating of repository instance in service_layer.

Comment: If you have 3 tiers architecture where the mvc tier has no direct access to the database, then you need to call the WCF Service Application from mvc controllers through a remote proxy class. This .NET class can be generated from the WCF schema in three ways: 1- add service reference from mvc project. 2- use wsdl.exe command linet tool. 3- look for dynamic proxy if available with NINJECT.

Comment: But I want to use WCF with Xamarin not with MVC controller...or maybe I missed something? You want me to call MVC controllers from WCF?

Comment: looks like you dont have 3 tiers architecture. You have xamarin -> WCF -> database. You have to choose between WCF and MVC in your case not both of them. Use WCF with webhttpbinding and rest structure or use asp.net web api or mvc. For three tiers, yes, xamarin -> mvc/api -> wcf -> database.